# PDF to Image conversion - Windows command line script

Tags: imagemagick

I have to write a windows command line shell script to convert pdf to Images. 
Sample command:

```
convert.exe -density 300x300 -resize 3508x <file>.pdf -units PixelsPerInch -profile srgb.icc <FILE>.jpg
```

This command works fine for pdfs with NON-White background but goes wrong with pdfs with WHITE background. Any idea how I can give a command that works for both?

Plus

1) If the PDF is converted to .png ( as opposed to .jpg) it works. Any idea why?

Answer (score -1):

This might be helpful, [Save pdf to jpeg using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775048/save-pdf-to-jpeg-using-c-sharp).

Also have a look [here](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ExportImages-sample.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).