# Convert bytes array to image of type jpeg in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, jpeg, typeconverter

Can I convert any bytes array (byte[]) to jpeg image in C# ?
For example, if I convert `text` or `word` or `pdf` file into bytes array , then Is it possible to convert this array to jpeg image in C# ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will need an external converter. What you *can* do is convert a bunch of bytes that already *is* a jpeg into an instance of a jpeg object. But if your byte array represents something that is not a jpg (or other graphics format) you cannot convert it to a jpg with native .NET means.

Comment: External resources are off topic here, but you can find examples in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775048/save-pdf-to-jpeg-using-c-sharp) answers. You will need a library for each conversion you want to do.