# Export Pdf to Image

Tags: c#, pdf

How can I Export an Pdf Document to an Image File.

Input is Stream
Output is Stream

I only found the Solution [Save pdf to jpeg using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775048/save-pdf-to-jpeg-using-c-sharp) but this is not suitable, because PdfiumViewer does not Support exporting Signature fields.

The Documents we want to Export contain Digital Signatures which are an Image. These Images should be exported as well.

Created with Signosign 2 Software. (https://en.signotec.com/products/signature-software/pdf-signature-for-desktop/signosign-2/)

Comment: You need to render the pdfs. There are plenty of "PDF-Printers" out there doing that. Some of which can also "print to image".

Comment: What about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905169/how-to-convert-pdf-files-to-image

Comment: sure there are plenty of PDF Printers, the Work has to be done in an webservice. We have a Pdf in Memory and want to convert it into an Image to Process it further in Memory. On a Webserver you can not print.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Isma C. I checked the 3 Alternatives. The first has been deleted, the second is a Printer, and the third is for Andoid only

Comment: In that case, you'll probably need to use some tool like Adobe SDK, iTextSharp, pdfsharp ... just to name a few. There's a plethora of them.

Comment: thanks für the Hint Fildor :-) we use iTextSharp for other purposes, but know no way to extract iamges. What I found is to copy pages into another PDF with iTextSharp which is converted with an command line tool. (Command line is not possible at web as well)